# Why is Java (Nashnorn library) not evaluationg JS code correctly?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have code that works fine in JavaScript IDE like Webstorm, but when I try to port it to Java, using the Nashorn library (to run JS within a Java program), **I get these errors:  "Name: undefined, Age: undefined"** (with possibly others to follow depending what's wrong here.)

Below is the full code. This coding approach below seems to work in general, but there are cases like this where I don't get the expected results.

Would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks!

---

```
public class JavaScriptEvaluationExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException
    {
        // Basic JavaScript evaluation
        String json = "{\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"John\",\n" +
                "    \"age\": 30,\n" +
                "    \"cars\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"Ford\",\n" +
                "            \"models\": [\n" +
                "                \"Fiesta\",\n" +
                "                \"Focus\",\n" +
                "                \"Mustang\"\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"BMW\",\n" +
                "            \"models\": [\n" +
                "                \"320\",\n" +
                "                \"X3\",\n" +
                "                \"X5\"\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"Fiat\",\n" +
                "            \"models\": [\n" +
                "                \"500\",\n" +
                "                \"Panda\"\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";
        
        String jsScript = "function parseJSONFields(param)\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "    var result = \"\";\n" +
                "    var carName =\"\" ;\n" +
                "    var models = \"\";\n" +
                "    var name = param.name + \",\";\n" +
                "    var age = param.age;\n" +
                "    result = \"Name: \" + name + \" Age: \" + age + \"\\n\";\n" +
                "    for (item in param.cars)\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        result  += \" \"+ \" >> \" + param.cars[item].name +\": \"\n" +
                "        result+= \" \"  + param.cars[item].models\n" +
                "        result += \"\\n\";\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "    return result;\n" +
                "}";

        System.out.println(runJS("parseJSONFields", json, jsScript));
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static Object runJS(String functionName, String param, String script) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException
   // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        Object resultString = "";
        String errorResultString = "";

        ScriptEngine js = null;
        try
        {
            if (param.length() > 0)
            {
                js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
                js.eval(script);
                Invocable inv = (Invocable) js;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorResultString = e.getMessage() + " ---> " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return errorResultString.length() > 0 ? errorResultString
                : ((Invocable) js).invokeFunction(functionName, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: You pass in the JSON as a `String`. That will be represented as a string in JavaScript, i.e. not as the object *described* by that JSON. *Either* parse it in Java code and pass in something that's accepted as an Object in the JS engine, or parse it in JavaScript (I don't know how to do either, or I'd have written this as an answer).

Comment: Please also note that _with the release of Java 11, Nashorn is deprecated, and will likely be removed from the JDK at a later time_.

Comment: Update -- Other JavaScript code works using the same technique.

Comment: The current release of GraalVM does not work for me at all. There are duplicated items in the mac installer and the code that worked in previous versions of GraalVM no longer work. Thus, I'm stuck with Nashorn for now...

Comment: Also notice that the "js.eval(script);" line of code does not throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied.

The problem was, as the first person noted, that I forgot the JSON.parse() statement to convert the string to a JSON object.

Thanks very much again.